# Sheaf cohomology on the formal completion of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ at its north pole

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology, cech-cohomology

Let $k$ be a field and let $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ be the projective line over $k$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a coherent sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^1_k$. The curve $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ is recovered by the two affine subschemes $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]$ and $\operatorname{Spec}k[x^{-1}]$. Thus, the sheaf cohomology of $\mathcal{F}$ is computed by the complex
$$C:=\left[\mathcal{F}(\operatorname{Spec} k[x])\oplus \mathcal{F}(\operatorname{Spec}k[x^{-1}])\stackrel{(x,y)\mapsto x-y}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{F}(\operatorname{Spec}k[x,x^{-1}])\right]$$
placed in degree $0$ and $1$.

We can easily show (by hand) that $C$ is also quasi-isomorphic to the complex
$$\left[\mathcal{F}(\operatorname{Spec} k[x])\oplus \mathcal{F}(\operatorname{Spec}k[[x^{-1}]])\stackrel{(x,y)\mapsto x-y}{\longrightarrow} \mathcal{F}(\operatorname{Spec}k((x^{-1})))\right]$$

**EDIT:** $\{\operatorname{Spec}k[[x^{-1}]]\to \mathbb{P}^1_k;\operatorname{Spec}k[x]\to \mathbb{P}^1_k\}$ forms a fpqc cover of $\mathbb{P}^1_k$, and further that the fpqc cohomology and Zariski cohomology coincide for quasi-coherent sheaves (e.g. Thm.2.20 of [notes from a class by J. de Jong](http://math.columbia.edu/%7Edejong/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/EtaleCohomology.pdf)). But this might not be the theoretical reason why both complexes are quasi-isomorphic as $\operatorname{Spec} k[[x^{-1}]]\times_{\mathbf{P}^1_k}\operatorname{Spec} k[x]$ is not $\operatorname{Spec} k((x^{-1}))$.

**Question:** What is the reason for this quasi-isomorphism?

Many thanks!

Comment: It seems that $Y=\operatorname{Spec} k[x] \sqcup \operatorname{Spec} k[[x^{-1}]]\to X=\mathbf{P}^1$ is an fppf cover with $Y\times_X Y$ the disjoint union of $\operatorname{Spec} k[x]$, $\operatorname{Spec} k[[x^{-1}]]$, and $\operatorname{Spec} k[[x^{-1}]][1/(x^{-1})$. The fppf cohomology of a coherent sheaf on an affine scheme vanishes, and fppf descent should give you the statement you want.

Comment: ...Further, this fppf cover refines the standard Zariski cover of $\mathbf{P}^1$, and so you get a map of Cech complexes, which then must be an isomorphism.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger I believe it is an fpqc cover, not fppf (since $k[[x^{-1}]]$ is not of finite presentation over $\mathbf{P}^1$), but this does not change the argument of course.

Comment: @DenisNardin sure, I meant fpqc, thanks!

Comment: @Stabilo the schemes $\operatorname{Spec} k[x] \amalg \operatorname{Spec} k[[x^{-1}]]$ and $\mathbf P^1$ are both quasicompact and separated, which easily implies the finiteness property of Tag [022B](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/022B).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @R.vanDobbendeBruyn. Let me see if I can complete the argument. First of all, $f_1:\operatorname{Spec} k[x]\to \mathbf P^1$ and $f_2:\operatorname{Spec} k[[x^{-1}]]\to \mathbf P^1$ are flat because they induce isomorphisms on local rings. So let $U\subset \mathbf P^1$ be an affine open. If $U=\operatorname{Spec}R$ does not contain the north pole, then $R\subset k[x]$. Thereby $U=f_1(\operatorname{Spec}R)$. On the other-hand, if $U$ equals $f_1(\operatorname{Spec}(R\cap k[x]))\cup f_2(\operatorname{Spec}k[[x^{-1}]])$. It is thus an fpqc cover. Am I right?

Comment: EDIT on the comment: "If not, $U$ equals...", instead of "On the other-hand, if$U$ equals...".

Comment: A warning: A naive application of fpqc descent applied to the cover $\mathrm{Spec} k[x]\sqcup \mathrm{Spec} k[[x^{-1}]]\to \mathbb P^1_k$ involves the fibre product $\mathrm{Spec} k[[x^{-1}]]\times_{\mathbb P^1_k} \mathrm{Spec} k[[x^{-1}]]$ which is a complete mess. I believe there must be a way to answer the question using fpqc descent, but I've never really seen a clear explanation. The thing you're looking for is the Beauville--Laszlo lemma.

Comment: Thank you very much @PeterScholze, I believe this leads me on a different path. I am now slightly confused by the following: B-L Lemma allows me to glue sheaves on $\operatorname{Spec}k[[x^{-1}]]$ and $\operatorname{Spec}k[x]$. But how can I obtain a statement on the cohomology groups? Sorry if this is very basic...

Comment: See [Tag 0BNI](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BNI) for some explanation, and Theorem 1.4 In Bhatt's [Algebraization and Tannaka duality](https://arxiv.org/abs/1404.7483) for a version for derived categories, which in particular implies statements about cohomology.

Comment: @PeterScholze Thanks a lot!